# Vagrant: Connecting to a remote MySQL server always times out

Tags: mysql, nginx, vagrant

I set up a [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) VirtualBox box for Debian Wheezy following [this instruction](https://mikegriffin.ie/blog/20130418-creating-a-debian-wheezy-base-box-for-vagrant/).

I installed nginx and php5-fpm on this virtual machine. I can access my guest machine via `127.0.0.1:8080` from host. It can also serve php files and `phpinfo()` works correctly, too.

However, when I try to access a remote MySQL server from a php file, the request always times out and I get a `504 Gateway Timeout` error.

I noticed the followings.

- In my nginx conf file, I have this line `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`.
- In `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, I have `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.
- `php5-fpm.sock` exists in `/var/run/`.
- If I use `127.0.0.1:9000` instead of the socket, I still get the `504 Gateway Timeout` error, but I get the error immediately without any waiting.
- I added `proxy_read_timeout 300;` in my nginx conf, but this did not solve the issue.

My Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "wheezy32"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "dev/bootstrap.sh"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network :public_network
end
```

My nginx conf

```
server {
    root /var/www/sites/mysite/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/www/logs/mysite/mysite.access_log;
    error_log /var/www/logs/mysite/mysite.error_log;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

            proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

`/var/www/logs/mysite/mysite.error_log`

```
2013/06/16 23:47:27 [error] 2567#0: *23 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
2013/06/16 23:47:27 [error] 2567#0: *23 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Here is how I attempt to connect to the remote MySQL server.

```
require_once('/var/www/sites/mysite/includes/db_constants.php');

try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=172.16.0.51;dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';

        $db = new PDO($dsn,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500');
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500');
        exit;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your MySQL server located? 172.16.x.x suggests a private IP range, is it on your dev machine or a server on the internet or only reachable with some kind of VPN? This may be a real network timeout connecting to it...

Comment: read this maybe it will help http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/504error.htm

Comment: @cmur2, That's right! I changed it to a public IP and now it worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cmur2 said, I was using the private IP to connect to the remove server, and that was why it did not work. I changed it to a public IP and now it is working correctly.